# How do I list all arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In code, I have:

```
house = ["red","blue","yellow"];
car = ["fast","big","safe"];
sofa = ["cozy","modern","elegant"];
```

How do I count and list all the arrays in my code?
Like "how many arrays do I have?"
answer "3 arrays - house, car, sofa".

Comment: Why would you need this? If you need a way to access the arrays in a dynamically, use a different data structure (such as an object of arrays). Or do you want to perform static code analysis (in which case you need a parser and traverse the AST).

Comment: Victor, I think you need to explain what you are trying to do.  That will help us give suggestions on better ways to solve your actual problem.

Comment: That is the thing: I have a list with all the universities of all states in brazil. Kinda like 20 universities per state. When I select a state a new select would open with all the universities that state has, but its 50 states and I dont want to type in every single name of the state.

Comment: Then you have to create a different data structure than the one in your question. The information you provided in your question isn't very valuable to potential answerers. Please expand your question and explain first with simple words what's your actual goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer based on your code and with fewer code lines:

```
var house = ["red","blue","yellow"];
var car = ["fast","big","safe"];
var sofa = ["cozy","modern","elegant"];
var arrayCount = 0;
var arrayString = "";
for (var property in window) {
    if (Array.isArray(window[property])){
        arrayCount++;
        arrayString += arrayCount > 1 ? ", " + property : property;
    }
}
console.log(arrayCount + " arrays - " + arrayString);
```

Check it running on https://jsbin.com/mumoxiyire/edit?js,console

Comment: Well, that's it. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Can you create a new array with the name of the arrays? Sorry if it's a lot to ask.

Comment: Yeah, I just did:
`var house = ["red","blue","yellow"];
var car = ["fast","big","safe"];
var sofa = ["cozy","modern","elegant"];
var arrayCount = 0;
var arraysAR = [];
for (var property in window) {
    if (Array.isArray(window[property])){
        arrayCount++;
        arraysAR.push(property);
    }
}`

Comment: as stated by  @foreyez its not the best idea to do this on the window object because if you ever want to add an array for other purposes that shouldn't be counted it will be hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would to be to put all your arrays in an object

```
Arrays = {
    house: ["red","blue","yellow"],
    cars: ["fast","big","safe"],
    sofa: ["cozy","modern","elegant"]
}
numberOfArrays = Object.keys(Arrays).length;
sentence = numberOfArrays + ' Arrays - ' + Object.keys(Arrays).join(', ');
```

`sentence` will be `3 Arrays - house, cars, sofa` in this example

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. You're declaring all arrays. So you always know the answer.

But you may declare it inside another array-wrapper, like this:

```
var items = [["red","blue","yellow"],
             ["fast","big","safe"],
             ["cozy","modern","elegant"]];
```

Then you could get the number of arrays by accessing this wrapper `items.length`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a collection of arrays that are related you should put them in an object rather than in the global namespace. Then you can call methods on that object to get the information you desire about the arrays.

```js
var MyArrays = {
  house: ["red", "blue", "yellow"],
  car: ["fast", "big", "safe"],
  sofa: ["cozy", "modern", "elegant"]
};

function countArrays(obj){
  var counter = 0;
  for(var key in obj)
    if(obj[key] instanceof Array)
      counter++;
  return counter;
}
function getArrayNames(obj){
  var names = [];
  for(var key in obj)
    if(obj[key] instanceof Array)
      names.push(key)
  return names;
}

var info = "There are " + countArrays(MyArrays) + " arrays: " + getArrayNames(MyArrays).join(", ");
```

Comment: I already have the arrays written. its like 50 arrays with 20 university names on each. I'll not rewrite the code, I just thought If I have them in a code, there should be a way to access them.

Comment: You could reuse these functions and just pass in the "window" object but if there are any other arrays anywhere else in your code it will count them and screw everything up. This is why we typically avoid polluting the global namespace, but like I said `countArrays(window)` and `getArrayNames(window)` should still work.

Comment: Not to mention you could always just find and replace all "=" with ":" and ";" with "," and then you would only have to add `var Universities = {` at the beginning and `};` at the end. It would take like 10 seconds and it would be done properly.

Answer (score -1):

```
var arrayCount = 0;
for (var property in window) {
    var obj = window[property];
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call( obj ) === '[object Array]')
        arrayCount++;
}

console.log(arrayCount);
```

edit: probably best not to do this on the window object, I'm getting different results on jsfiddle and on jsbin. :>

Comment: It's definitely a correct answer. And he will definitely get an unexpected result. :)

Comment: That's it man. Thanks a lot.

Comment: don't mark it as right.. it's not right yet. lol

Comment: It counted right in my example code.

Comment: yeah but I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't work if those arrays have a var next to them

Comment: just tested it again, seems to be working just fine

Comment: Well, it says that there are 3 arrays in that page (stackoverflow.com). And it could be any number. :) `window` is a global object, and anyone can change it and add anything. You can not control it. And you should not rely on such things. It will lead to nasty bugs.